# Dimension of that sub Vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering how to find the dimension of the sub vector space  $A=\{u \in L(E) \ \vert \ u\circ v = v\circ u=0\}$ of $L(E)$, where $L(E)$ is the set of endomorphism of $E$ (i.e linear map from $E$ to $E$) and $v \in L(E)$. Thanks !

Comment: For an endomorphism $v\in L(E)$, we need to find those maps $u\in L(E)$ such that $\operatorname{im} u\subset \ker v$ and $\operatorname{im} v\subset \ker u$.  Can you approach this now?

Comment: @Ian Thanks, yes I already noticed that but failed to find a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $v \in L(E)$, let $u \in A$ be arbitrary.  Because $v \circ u = 0$, we know that $\text{Image}(u) \subset \ker(v)$.  Because  $u \circ v = 0$, we know $\text{Image}(v) \subset \ker(u)$.

Let $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k$ be a basis for $\ker(v)$.

Let $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_j$ be a basis for $\text{Image}(v)$.  Extend this basis to form the basis $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ of $E$.

We note that $u$ must take the span of $\beta_1,\cdots,\beta_j$ to $0$, and its image must fall within the span of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k$.  However, we may freely choose where within the span of $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k$ $u$ takes the span of $\beta_{j+1},\dots,\beta_n$.

That is, 
$$
A \cong \text{Hom}(\text{span}(\beta_{j+1},\dots,\beta_n),\text{span}(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k))
$$
It follows that $\dim(A) = (n - \dim(\text{Image}(v))) \times \dim(\ker(v))$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, we have
$$
\dim(A) = \dim(\ker(v))^2
$$

Comment: I think I know this but how can you say "extend this basis to form the basis... of E"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks for this wonderful proof !!

Comment: @TylerHilton any linearly independent set of vectors in a vector space can be [extended to a basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Extending_to_a_basis).  Here's [an example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465870/how-to-extend-a-basis).

Comment: @jerry You're welcome (: